# RavenDB import from relational database

Tags: database-migration, ravendb, ravendb-studio, ravendb5

Is it possible to import data from a relational database to RavenDB using a complex query?
This query joins several tables, more than 20 in a very complex way, something that is not achievable using its Migration tool in RavenDB studio.

I was thinking in ETL but there is no path from SQL --> to --> RavenDB.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can always import documents from a SQL database into a RavenDB database through the Studio, under **Tasks > Import Data > From SQL**. Is that helpful ?

Comment: @Danielle In this case it is not possible due to the necessity of joining more than 20 tables

Answer (score 0):

Actually using RavenDB tools this this not possible.